# Populate a combobox based on of the selection of another combobox in c# window forms

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, combobox

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the text of my combobox to my stored procedure which takes 1 parameter (of type string) and it will return data based on that string. That string comes from the combobox list so for example in the combobox 1 if the user selects testing1 then the stored procedure will read that testing1 and then my stored procedure will return its data. The problem I am having is to read the data from the combobox basing on the user select and then pass that string data to my stored procedure and add it to the parameter.

I have tried many methods but none worked so far the only way it works is if I put a string name to my stored procedure but I just did it as a test but I can't work like that, it needs to come from the combobox.

Here is my code that does not work was trying to add the selected item from the combobox but I know that if I use the combobox event selectedIndexchanged it might work but I need the results of this outside that event because I need to use that method somewhere else in the code and not just inside combobox event

```
public void GetFinishedGoods()
{
        try
        {

            var context = _manufacturingDbContext;

            var finishedGoods = context.FinishedGoodByOrder(Cmb_MfgOrder.GetItemText(Cmb_MfgOrder.SelectedItem));

            foreach (var finishedGoodList in finishedGoods)
            {
                Cmb_FgLookupCode.Items.Add(finishedGoodList);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

here is the same code but when I add just a string it works then the second combobox returns data but instead of adding a string the data needs to come from the combobox not just a string, also the finishedGoodByOrder is the name of the stored procedure and "TESTING1" is the string parameter the stored procedure needs to return data

```
  public void GetFinishedGoods()
  {
    try
    {
        var context = _manufacturingDbContext;

        var finishedGoods = context.FinishedGoodByOrder("TESTING1"));

        foreach (var finishedGoodList in finishedGoods)
        {
            Cmb_FgLookupCode.Items.Add(finishedGoodList);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

So to summarize this, the goal is to somehow send the selected data from combobox 1 to my `finishedGoodByOrder` stored procedure and add it to the parameter so my stored procedure can return the data from that stored procedure to the second combobox.

Adding here an test image of the so as you can see if the user select combobox 1 in the example you see TESTING1 then in that select text TESTING1 or any data from that combobox it should be pass to my stored procedure so it can send read that and display the data to combobox2. so I need help to read the data from combobox1 then send that data to my stored procedure `FinishedGoodByOrder`, then it can return the list of data to combobox 2

[image]

Comment: The feature that you are trying to accomplish is called Cascading. I think this link might help you: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-combobox-in-windows-application-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Okay I will take a look at this and see if it works for my task I need to do, I will get back to you with the final results.

Comment: Sounds good @NewCoder

Comment: after taking a look at that link, they are using dapper I think. I am using Entity Framework, all I need is just send the data from the selected combobox 1 and add that string to my stored procedure because my stored procedure will do the job to polulate the data to combobox 2, there is not other way than that cascading way?

Comment: I see. Okay then I will share a new link with you that has entity framework. I will need to check and then update you. If possible, I will add an answer to it so that you can directly implement in your application.

Comment: great thanks let me know when you a solution.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to my issue? please let me know.

Comment: I had found many documents but all of them are simple queries. They are not using Entity Framework.I am still finding the solution from video tutorials, and will get back to you by today EOD.

Comment: thanks for the help, I am also looking for a solution, thanks again any update please let me know.